# How to display a link to an empty blob on an HTML page (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, csv, export

The following vanilla JS code is being used to export form data that has been converted to a blob, and saved to localstorage, out to a CSV file:

```
let ourData = localStorage.getItem("entry_list");
ourData = JSON.parse(ourData); 

const titleKeys = Object.keys(ourData[0])

const refinedData = []

refinedData.push(titleKeys)

ourData.forEach(item => {
  refinedData.push(Object.values(item))  
})

let csvContent = ''

refinedData.forEach(row => {
  csvContent += row.join(',') + '\n'
})

const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8,' })
const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
const link = document.createElement('a')
link.setAttribute('href', objUrl)
link.setAttribute('download', 'export.csv')
link.textContent = 'export'

document.querySelector('span.export').appendChild(link)
```

To initiate this export I use the following link on the main page:

```
<span class="export"></span></div>
```

The problem I have is that the link will only display if there is data in the blob / localstorage. For example, if user data has been entered into the form, and the page is refreshed, the link will display. If there is no user data entered into the form, the link is not displayed.

I want the link text "export" to display always, whether there is user data present or not, and I definitely need to avoid forcing the user to refresh after the enter data into a blank form.

I hope this makes sense and if you can tell me where I am going wrong, or why this behavior is occurring, I would be very grateful. I think I may have to create the empty blob first...?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I suppose this line here is crashing when nothing is in storage `ourData = JSON.parse(ourData);`. You should first check that ourData contains data.

Comment: So I think this means use a conditional statement such as an IF... What if it is indeed empty... what should the ELSE be? I don't quite get the logic. I want the link to display always, regardless if empty data or containing data. I am still trying to learn JS. Thank you for replying!

Comment: "I don't quite get the logic." ... if it doesnt contain data, then `JSON.parse()` will crash and terminate the remainder of the script. You could use an if block to condition.

Comment: But before you go hacking away at the problem(s) blindly, open your browser's dev tools console first to see what errors are being reported by javascript. Doesnt seem like you are aware of such tools. (Goto Options, look for "developer tools" or the like).

Comment: I am aware the tools in the browser however there is not error being produced. I think it might be because the data is being taken from another object `entry_list` which does exist. I was unaware that JSON.parse would just crash without data being present. clearly I have to gain ore knowledge but it is a vast new language and takes time. If anyone if kind enough to suggest or provide an example of the correct way too approach such a problem, I would be very grateful. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself.
One lined needed to be fixed to resolve the problem:

```
const titleKeys = Object.keys(ourData[0]);
```

to

```
const titleKeys = Object.keys(ourData[0] || {});
```

Answer (score -2):

The behavior you're encountering is likely due to the fact that when there is no data in local storage (localStorage.getItem("entry_list") returns null), the code does not execute further to create the link element. To always display the "export" link, you can modify your code to conditionally create the link element regardless of whether there is data in local storage.

```html
// Retrieve data from local storage
let ourData = localStorage.getItem("entry_list");
ourData = ourData ? JSON.parse(ourData) : []; // Check if data exists, otherwise initialize as empty array

// Create CSV content
const titleKeys = Object.keys(ourData[0] || {}); // Use empty object if no data exists to avoid errors
const refinedData = [];
refinedData.push(titleKeys);

ourData.forEach(item => {
  refinedData.push(Object.values(item));  
});
enter code here
let csvContent = '';

refinedData.forEach(row => {
  csvContent += row.join(',') + '\n';
});

// Create Blob and link only if there is data or if it's an empty array
const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8,' });
const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', objUrl);
link.setAttribute('download', 'export.csv');
link.textContent = 'export';

// Always append the link to the span, regardless of data presence
document.querySelector('span.export').appendChild(link);
```

Comment: That is a ChatGPT generated answer. [Such answers are banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned). Also SO does not support localStorage in snippets and you missed the SPAN from the question so the snippet will not even run (does not help you pasted the code into the wrong pane)

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not work. The #comments are a helpful tip. The check for empty object make sense but I cannot get it to work, thanks... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).